# Python List Class __contains__ Method Functionality

Tags: python, list, class, function, contains

Does the `__contains__` method of a list class check whether an object itself is an element of a list, or does it check whether the list contains an element equivalent to the given parameter?

Could you give me an example to demonstrate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
>>> a = [[]]
>>> b = []
>>> b in a
True
>>> b is a[0]
False
```

This proves that it is a value check (by default at least), not an identity check.  Keep in mind though that a class can if desired override `__contains__()` to make it an identity check.  But again, by default, no.

Comment: No, Python performs the identity check first and then only checks the value if the identity check fails. See the example below.

Answer (score 7):

Python lists (and tuples) first check whether an object itself is an element of a list (using the `is` operator) and only if that is False then does it check whether the object is equal to an item in the list (using the `==` operator). You can see this by creating an object that is not equal to itself:

```
>>> class X:
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...             return False
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> x == x
False
```

However since `x is x`, `__contains__` still recognises that this object is in a list

```
>>> x in [1, 'a', x, 7]
True
```

That is, a lists `__contains__` method is equivalent to:

```
def __contains__(self, other):
    return any(other is item or other == item for item in self)
```

Comment: And a quote from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) to back this up:
_"For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`."_

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the class how it does the check. For the builtin `list` it uses the `==` operator; otherwise you couldn't e.g. use `'something' in somelist` safely.

To be more specific, it check if the item is equal to an item in the list - so internally it's most likely a `hash(a) == hash(b)` comparison; if the hashes are equal the objects itself are probably compared, too.

Comment: It won't be just a check of hashes - hashes can be equal without the values being equal.

Comment: This is wrong. I just defined a `__eq__` method which has been (involuntarily) picked up by `__contains__` or `in`. Therefore, it's most likely `list` implements a `a.__eq__(b)` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It checks the value

```
>>> x = 8888
>>> y = 8888
>>> list1 = [x]
>>> print(id(x))
140452322647920
>>> print(id(y))
140452322648016
>>> y in list1
True
```