# For comparisons in Python, why is using IN faster than looping ==?

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to understand what is going on under the hood a bit more in Python.  I have two snippets of code, each having list1 and list2 as variables containing a list of integers:

## Snippet 1:

```
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x == y: True
```

## Snippet 2:

```
for y in list2:
    if y in list1: True
```

Both of them compare list 1 and list 2 and tell us whether they have anything in common, but snippet 2 executes about twice as fast as snippet 1, and I am trying to understand why.

What is actually going on when using if y *in* list, which examines each element and determines if they match, as opposed to looping through each element for comparison, that makes it so much faster?

Comment: The difference is just that one of the loops is in optimized C/C++ code, the other is done by interpreting Python.

Comment: Is `True` supposed to be `return True`? Of not, neither loop actually tells you whether they found a match.

Comment: And the loop doesn't stop when it finds a match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python == with or vs. in list comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877313/python-with-or-vs-in-list-comparison)

Comment: The code itself is designed to evaluate every value in both lists, which would be the worst-case scenario.  I think Omar's response is what I was looking for- I don't know why I couldn't find it when I searched.  Thanks for the responses!