# How to check if a list of numpy arrays contains a given test array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of `numpy` arrays, say,

```
a = [np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3)]
```

and I have a test array, say

```
b = np.random.rand(3, 3)
```

I want to check whether `a` contains `b` or not. However

```
b in a
```

throws the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

What is the proper way for what I want?

Comment: Did you try list comprehension?

Comment: what do you mean by list comprehension? In my understanding list comprehension means something like

Comment: [ a for a in some_iterable]

Comment: what is the point of list comprehension in this task?

Comment: Why not make `a` a `3x3x3` array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just make one array of shape `(3, 3, 3)` out of `a`:

```
a = np.asarray(a)
```

And then compare it with `b` (we're comparing floats here, so we should use `isclose()`)

```
np.all(np.isclose(a, b), axis=(1, 2))
```

For example:

```
a = [np.random.rand(3,3),np.random.rand(3,3),np.random.rand(3,3)]
a = np.asarray(a)
b = a[1, ...]       # set b to some value we know will yield True

np.all(np.isclose(a, b), axis=(1, 2))
# array([False,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

As highlighted by @jotasi the truth value is ambiguous due to element-wise comparison within the array. 
There was a previous answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766194/testing-whether-a-numpy-array-contains-a-given-row). Overall your task can be done in various ways:

1. list-to-array:

You can use the "in" operator by converting the list to a (3,3,3)-shaped array as follows:

```
    >>> a = [np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3), np.random.rand(3, 3)]
    >>> a= np.asarray(a)
    >>> b= a[1].copy()
    >>> b in a
    True
```

2. np.all:

   ```
   >>> any(np.all((b==a),axis=(1,2)))
   True
   ```
3. list-comperhension:
   This done by iterating over each array:

   ```
   >>> any([(b == a_s).all() for a_s in a])
   True
   ```

Below is a speed comparison of the three approaches above:

[Speed Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4tFG.png)

```
import numpy as np
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: np.asarray([np.random.rand(3*3).reshape(3,3) for i in range(n)]),
    kernels=[
        lambda a: a[-1] in a,
        lambda a: any(np.all((a[-1]==a),axis=(1,2))),
        lambda a: any([(a[-1] == a_s).all() for a_s in a])
        ],
    labels=[
        'in', 'np.all', 'list_comperhension'
        ],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(1,20)],
    xlabel='Array size',
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so `in` doesn't work because it's effectively doing

```
def in_(obj, iterable):
    for elem in iterable:
        if obj == elem:
            return True
    return False
```

Now, the problem is that for two ndarrays `a` and `b`, `a == b` is an array (try it), not a boolean, so `if a == b` fails. The solution is do define a new function

```
def array_in(arr, list_of_arr):
     for elem in list_of_arr:
        if (arr == elem).all():
            return True
     return False

a = [np.arange(5)] * 3
b = np.ones(5)

array_in(b, a) # --> False
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because if `a` and `b` are `numpy arrays` then `a == b` doesn't return `True` or `False`, but `array` of `boolean` values after comparing `a` and `b` element-wise.

You can try something like this:

```
np.any([np.all(a_s == b) for a_s in a])
```

- `[np.all(a_s == b) for a_s in a]` Here you are creating list of `boolean` values, iterating through elements of `a` and checking if all elements in `b` and particular element of `a` are the same.
- With `np.any` you can check if any element in your array is `True`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41957167), the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) states that:

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e or x == e for e in y).

`a[0]==b` is an array, though, containing an element-wise comparison of `a[0]` and `b`. The overall truth value of this array is obviously ambiguous. Are they the same if all elements match, or if most match of if at least one matches? Therefore, `numpy` forces you to be explicit in what you mean. What you want to know, is to test whether all elements are the same. You can do that by using `numpy`'s [`all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) method:

```
any((b is e) or (b == e).all() for e in a)
```

or put in a function:

```
def numpy_in(arrayToTest, listOfArrays):
    return any((arrayToTest is e) or (arrayToTest == e).all()
               for e in listOfArrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_equal from numpy

```
    import numpy as np
    a = [np.random.rand(3,3),np.random.rand(3,3),np.random.rand(3,3)]
    b = np.random.rand(3,3)

    for i in a:
        if np.array_equal(b,i):
            print("yes")
```

Comment: Actually, `(a==b).all()` is not slower than `np.array_equal(a, b)`. The main difference is, that `np.array_equal` tests the shape of the array first.